# Facebook adgroup creation - Invalid parameter

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I am having an issue promoting an unpublished page post via the ads-api.
This was previously working ok for me, but began causing problems yesterday.

I first create an ad_campaign, and then, using the returned campaign_id, I attempt to create an adgroup.

The response from the server is

```
array(1) {
  'error' =>
   array(3) {
     'message' =>
       string(53) "(#100) Invalid parameter: adgroup_spec["campaign_id"]"
     'type' =>
       string(14) "OAuthException" 
     'code' => int(100)
   }
}
```

I have verified that I am sending over the correct, newly created campaign_id.

Another point of interest; when I use the UI to delete the ad_campaign afterwards, I am told that I do not have permission to do so. User XXXX does not have permission to access campaign YYYY.

I'm thinking this must be an access_token/permission issue but I'm stumped. The ad objects are created using the user's token, and the unpublished page post is created using the page's access token.

NB: I can provide snippets if needs be, but I'm fairly sure this is a problem with the object creation flow as opposed to a code issue.

Has anyone seen anything similar?

Cheers, Gary

**Update with POST data**

```
array(7) {
  'campaign_id' =>
    int(6013621027457)
  'bid_type' =>
    int(6)
  'bid_info' =>
    string(37) "{"clicks":10,"reach":10,"actions":80}"
  'conversion_specs' =>
    string(66) "{"action.type":"offsite_conversion","offsite_pixel":6013619180457}"
  'creative' =>
    string(86) "{"type":27,"object_id":407012979370770,"auto_update":false,"story_id":565852233486843}"
  'name' =>
    string(23) "PropelAd (via PropelAd)"
  'targeting' =>
    string(95) "{"countries":["IE","AE","GB"],"friends_of_connections":[407012979370770],"page_types":["feed"]}"
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the body of your POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it happens to me as well from time to time when uploading ads.

It's very statistical, and it seems to be an off-sync between Facebook servers (the campaign was already successfully uploaded, but the ad-request-handler does not recognize that id).
Wait a few seconds, and try again - after a few shots, it will always work (usually there's no problem, it's pretty rare but happens - and never lasted more than a minute of not-recognizing).

Perhaps it happened more today, due to the general Facebook failures.

I can only assume/hope that Facebook keep track of these errors, and are working on minimizing them by syncing their servers better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark. I am awaiting a response from Facebook as to how best to handle this possible delay, but cheers for the potential workaround.

Comment: It should only take a few seconds for a newly created campaign to be usable for ad creation, if you're seeing significant delays that's a bug which should be reported in the API bug tracker. As you said, there were widespread issues with Facebook today which may have made this worse than usual so it may be an issue which has passed

Comment: Gary - I am not sure which IDE/Language you're using, but if you're using Visual Studio take a look at the "Topaz" application block from the Enterprise Library.  That's what I use for operations that fail and need retry capabilities.  The retry code works perfectly and gets around this issue that I've also seen.  It also gets around the occasional 503 error that pops up.  The nice thing is you can configure delays on the next retry, how many retries, etc... It's very useful and has become a core component of our ads code base here.

Answer (score 0):

Yep - we are currently putting a lot of time in checking why do ad group fail on unpublished posts - specifically on posts scheduled in the future.

The behavior is very inconsistent. The errors we get are slightly different: "Could not save ad", "Invalid ad creative". The errors are not reported on all ad groups but mostly on one of the ad groups of a whole batch.

We do make sure that the campaign start time is equal or AFTER the time the post is scheduled to.

When we publish the post now and test with the same campaign structure it succeeds (although this also succeeds sometimes on the second try - like it was mentioned here, that the campaign takes some time maybe to become fully valid)

A related bug I opened is here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/593878450648811?browse=external_tasks_search_results_52662e53c59bd2e63625449

Comment: Well - doing retries on the ad groups that failed ONLY solved this issue for me. Previously I did retry but on the whole batch.
When trying to recreate only the ads that failed - they go though.
This is definitely a behavior that should be fixed.